# Single precision math in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c, ieee-754

I'm re-implementing some C code in JavaScript, and in order to pass tests, I need the JavaScript code return the same result as the C code. The C code exclusively deals with single precision floating-point numbers (while JavaScript's `number` is double precision).

For example, in C, `-3.12744117f + 8.60676003f` equals `5.47931862f`. In JavaScript, `-3.12744117 + 8.60676003` equals `5.47931886`, which is different (`Math.fround` returns `5.479319095611572`, which is even more off).

I'm aware that the JavaScript result is technically "more correct", but what I'm aiming at here is coherence with the less precise C-counterpart.

Is there a way to apply 32-bit operations in JavaScript? Do I manually need to implement the IEEE 574 standard by hand, or are there other ways?

Comment: You can compile C code for use in browsers that support WebAssembly, https://caniuse.com/#feat=wasm  Support is pretty descent nowadays too.  So rather than converting your C code, just re-use it.

Comment: @Keith I thought about this as well, but the C code is part of a huge project that isn't very well structured, and it would basically mean re-writing the same logic in C.

Comment: Maybe OT, but shouldn't those tests, which are dealing with floating point numbers, take into account rounding errors in the first place?

Comment: @Bob__ I tried to apply some rounding when comparing the result, but the problem is that I'm dealing with 3D meshes which are run through translation matrices, and the resulting rounding errors go up above the decimal point. What I'm doing is comparing the final meshes, and if I just compare the n-th power of 10, the tests become kind of useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt should be fruitful if your were to convert the operands prior applying the operation;

```
Math.fround(Math.fround(-3.12744117) + Math.fround(8.60676003))
```

Alternately, the JavaScript [Float32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array) typed arrays shall be an alternate means. For instance;

```
(new Float32Array([-3.12744117, 8.60676003])).reduce((a, e) => Math.fround(a + e))
```

The both expedients yield a value of *5.479318618774414* which is equivalent to the expected C counterpart answer rounded to eight decimal place.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks promising! Any idea how to round back the computed result to 32-bit float to get rid of the additional digits? Is rounding to 8 digits enough?

Comment: @phreezie `Math.round(5.479318618774414 * Math.pow(10, 8)) / Math.pow(10, 8);`

Comment: @phreezie The `toFixed` shall do it; `(5.479318618774414).toFixed(8)`

Comment: Prepending the expression with `+` should do the trick; `+(5.479318618774414).toFixed(8)`

Comment: I think I'll also need to consider how many digits are before the dot. Something like `const f = Math.pow(10, 8 - Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(f8)))); return Math.round(f8 * f) / f;`, right?

Comment: The “added digits” are merely an artifact of JavaScript’s default formatting of numbers. You should not try to get rid of them by doing arithmetic on the number—that will produce a number that is different from the 32-bit floating-point value you seek. Instead, using formatting functions/controls to format the output with the desired number of digits.

Comment: Understood, this is only applied to the final result I'm comparing.